# how to you use execvp() one by one

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, fork

I want to use execvp twice 1 by 1 for 2 commands,
the new program I want to awake is hcp with a couple of parameters
and I am using this like that

```
int pid = 0;
char* spec_command[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product","Performance", NULL};
char* spec_command2[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product","Threat Prevention", NULL};
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) 
{
    execvp("/usr/bin/hcp", spec_command);
    execvp("/usr/bin/hcp", spec_command2);
}
```

but just one of them is executed?
how can I cause both of them work?
thanks

Edit-----

didnt work :( my code

```
const char* spec_command[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product","Performance", NULL};

const char* spec_command2[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product","Threat Prevention", NULL}; 

disableThreatPrevention(spec_command); 

disableThreatPrevention(spec_command2);



void disableThreatPrevention(const char* spec_command[]) { 

int pid = 0 ;
 pid = fork(); 
if (pid == 0) 
{ 
   execvp("/usr/bin/hcp", spec_command) 
   exit(1);
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work that way. `execvp` doesn't return unless it fails. So you need to `fork` and `execvp`, and `wait` for that process to finish. Then you can `fork` and `execvp` again.

Comment: It might be much easier to use `system()`.

Comment: Or, you could use `char* spec_command[] = {"/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/hcp --enable-product Performance; /usr/bin/hcp --enable-product 'Threat Prevention'", NULL};`, and just call `execv` once.

Comment: didnt work well , just one of them worked :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `fork()` twice since `execvp` replaces the current process completely and never returns (unless it fails).

Example:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void run(const char* file, char* argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        execvp(file, argv);
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char* spec_command[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product", "Performance",
                            NULL};
    char* spec_command2[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product",
                             "Threat Prevention", NULL};
    run("/usr/bin/hcp", spec_command);
    run("/usr/bin/hcp", spec_command2);

    int wstatus;
    while(wait(&wstatus) != -1) {}
}
```

This runs both commands in parallel. If you want to wait for the first one to finish before starting the second one, put a `wait` after the first `run` too - or in the the `run` function. If you want to continue the program without `wait`ing for the processes to finish, skip the `wait`.

---

If you want to run the commands in sequence - but still in the background, you could expand the above further by giving all commands to run as an array to `run` and loop over them and execute them one-by-one in a background process.

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    const char *filepath;
    char **argv;
} command;

pid_t run_in_sequence_in_background(command cmds[], size_t count) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // in first child
        // loop over all the commands and run them one by one in sequence
        for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            pid = fork();
            if(pid == 0) {
                // in grandchild
                execvp(cmds[i].filepath, cmds[i].argv);
                fprintf(stderr, "FAILED TO START %s\n", cmds[i].filepath);
                exit(1);
            } else if(pid != -1) {
                // in first child, wait for the grandchild
                int wstatus;
                waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0);
            }
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    return pid;
}


int main() {
    char* spec_command[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product", "Performance",
                            NULL};
    char* spec_command2[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product",
                             "Threat Prevention", NULL};

    command cmds[] = {
        {"/usr/bin/hcp", spec_command},
        {"/usr/bin/hcp", spec_command2}
    };

    pid_t pid = run_in_sequence_in_background(cmds, sizeof cmds / sizeof *cmds);

    // do other stuff - the hcp commands runs in the background now

    // if you want to wait for the background process:
    if(pid != -1) {
        int wstatus;
        waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0);
    }
}
```

or simpler, let `argv[0]` in your `spec_command`s be the filename to execute:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t run_in_sequence_in_background(char **cmds[], size_t count) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // in first child
        // loop over all the commands and run them one by one in sequence
        for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            pid = fork();
            if(pid == 0) {
                // in grandchild
                execvp(cmds[i][0], cmds[i]);
                fprintf(stderr, "FAILED TO START %s\n", cmds[i][0]);
                exit(1);
            } else if(pid != -1) {
                // in first child, wait for the grandchild
                int wstatus;
                waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0);
            }
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    return pid;
}


int main() {
    char* spec_command[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product", "Performance",
                            NULL};
    char* spec_command2[] = {"/usr/bin/hcp", "--enable-product",
                             "Threat Prevention", NULL};

    char** cmds[] = {spec_command, spec_command2};

    pid_t pid = run_in_sequence_in_background(cmds, sizeof cmds / sizeof *cmds);

    // do other stuff - the hcp commands runs in the background now

    // if you want to wait for the background process:
    if(pid != -1) {
        int wstatus;
        waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: the while will block my program to be continued?,  since I  need that these commands should run async, and the program should run without them or wait for them
If will I put down the 2 bottom lines , then the main program will run as usuall?
int wstatus;
while(wait(&wstatus) != -1) {}

Comment: @yonatancohen Yes, the `wait`s will block until the `hcp` programs are done. If you skip the `wait`, the `hcp` will run in the background. Depending on the signal situation, they _may_ get killed if your main program terminates though.

Comment: I tried the case without the wait, and run the 2 commands, but just one worked.

Comment: @yonatancohen Then put a `wait` after the first one. Perhaps the program can't handle two requests at the same time - or perhaps the program simply doesn't work like you expect and only enables the first - or last - product you give it as an argument.

Comment: thanks, helped me alot to understand :) , will try

Comment: @yonatancohen You're welcome! Please let me know if it doesn't work out (unless you come to the conclusion that it's a problem with the actual `hcp` program itself of course).

Comment: didnt work, i added a comment

Comment: It worked with the wait, but I am afraid about blocking the main thread,
There is away to cause to the main thread of the process to run without blocking, and 2 other threads to run separately, and between them, 1 will wait for the 2nd.?

Comment: put a sleep for 1 sec solved that(hope this will be enough, apperntly hcp process dosnt work well with multiply request.

Comment: @yonatancohen A `sleep` is rarely the proper solution. I added a better solution to my answer.

Comment: can I  get some note about this calculation in this line, - sizeof cmds / sizeof *cmds.
````
char** cmds[] = {spec_command, spec_command2};

pid_t pid = run_in_sequence_in_background(cmds, sizeof cmds / sizeof *cmds);
```````
what is calculated?

Comment: @yonatancohen `sizeof cmds / sizeof *cmds` calculates how many elements there are in the `cmds` array. It's instead of hardcoding `2`. If you add another element to the array, the calculation will then result in `3`.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, but what calculated in size of cmds - counting the number of elements ?
or counted the number of characters in the array?
size of *cmds - I assume it is 8 bytes (in most of the OS) since it is pointer . right?

Comment: @yonatancohen It's counting the elements. It takes the complete size of the `cmds` array in bytes and divides it with the size (again in bytes) of a single element. That results in the number of elements in the array.